# Filtering Applicatives

Tags: haskell

I am doing NICTA Haskell course and stuck on the last part of `Applicative`, here is my progress.

Basically, we are to filter a List with a predicate that produce a List in an Applicative context.

```
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
filtering _ Nil = pure Nil
filtering f (x :. rest) = 
        let whole = lift2 (:.) (pure x) (filtering f rest) in
        lift2 filter (const <$> f x) whole
```

So `whole` here is the full unfiltered list, so I lift a `filter`, and the added const in `(const <$> f x)` is to satisfy the `(a -> Bool)` requirement in `filter`.

All is well and it is compiled successfully, but it fails one of the test case so something must be wrong here.

For instance, `filtering (Id . even) [4,5,6]` only return `Id [4]` as opposed to `Id [4,6]` (Id is just a container and is an Applicative.)

Do I make any mistake somewhere?

Comment: What's `Id`, and what does `filtering` have to do with `sequence`?

Comment: @luqui If you assume `sequence` should be `filtering` and `Id` is a constructor for trivial `Applicative` instance , the question makes sense.

Comment: Why are you both recursing on the list and also running filter on it? Both of these operations access the entire list, seemingly giving you square complexity instead of linear

Comment: Typo, sorry guys.. That should be filtering

Comment: @tohava I don't know how to change `(:.)` into `if f x then (:.) else skip` or something like that because the Bool is on a context.. any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is `(const <$> f x)`.  That function is going to be used to examine the whole list, but it's only going to provide the result of `f` on the current `x`. That means when it's working on the `[5,6]` sublist, it's going to essentially be `filter (const False) [5,6]`, which results in an empty list.

You can't call on `filter` to do this for you, because it's just not the right shape. Something like this will always happen. Instead, just focus on including the current element or not, and let recursion handle the rest of the list properly. (I'm trying not to say more because the goal of doing the course is to figure it out for yourself, of course.)

Comment: Ah! that's right..
How do I tweak `(:.)` in the first `lift2` so that I can skip things? The problem here is that the Bool is inside a context

Comment: @bluebelle Hint: To get the `Bool` available as input for your `(:.)` replacement, also change your `(pure x)` (which you don't need, since you have `x` available as a parameter already) into `(f x)`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm confused by what you think "the full unfiltered list" is needed for, and I think so are you. The full unfiltered list it `x :. rest`, you already have that!

Apparently, you mean "the whole result as it would be if the predicate always yielded `True`... but that doesn't make any sense, because you'd basically predict that it *would* always yield `True`.

What you need to consider, instead of this `whole` thing, is two applicative-wrapped values: the result of the predicate at the head – that's just `f x :: f Bool`. And, as the recursion, *the filtered rest of the list*, `filtering f rest :: f (List a)`.

Now, as you've apparently noticed `liftA2` is often the easiest way to combine two `Applicative`-wrapped values (though `<*>` actually tends to make for neater code). Recall

```
liftA2 :: (a->b->c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

In this case,

```
liftA2 :: (Bool->List a->List a) -> f Bool -> f (List a) -> f (List a)
```

So you need a function `Bool->List a->List a`, which prepends `x` if the boolean is true and otherwise leaves the lists as it is. Well, it shouldn't be a problem to define that in a local `where` block.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is much simpler if instead of attempting it in one function, you break it into smaller subproblems.

The first hint I'd give is that it looks very much like a problem for the [`Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) class, which includes this method whose signature that should make you go "hmmm!":

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

By the funny `List` type in your problem, I gather the course you're taking doesn't allow to use library functions to solve the problem.  I don't very much agree with this practice; I think the best way to learn is the following two-step process:

1. Solve the problem using library functions.  This way you learn the libraries, and more importantly, you learn how to break the problem down into smaller, more generic ones.
2. Write your own version of the library functions you used.  This way you learn how the library-based solution works, all the way down.

So I'd suggest that as a subproblem, you should take a shot at writing your own version of `Traverse` for your `List` type.

Next subproblem: using `traverse`, it should be straightforward to write this function:

```
tagWithBool :: (a -> f Bool) -> -> List a -> f (List (Bool, a))
```

Once you have this, the next step I would do is to write this function:

```
-- Remove the items tagged with `False`, and eliminate the tags.
removeFalse :: List (Bool, a) -> List a
```

Again, I'd recommend to make full use of utility functions like `map` and `filter` when you write this, and after you have it working correctly, write your own version of the functions you used as an extra exercise.  (Actually, given the non-standard `List` type in your problem, you are pretty much forced to write your own versions to solve the problem this way.)

Once you have all of these, you can write:

```
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
filtering p xs = fmap removeFalse (tagWithBool xs)
```

Note that this uses `fmap`, so you'll have to implement `Functor` for the `List` type (or just a `mapList :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b` function).

Answer (score 0):

How about this one (i am using normal lists, not your ctor)

```
seq f [] = []
seq x:xs = lift2 (:) x (seq xs)
remove (x:xs) (y:ys) = (if y then [x] else []) ++ remove xs ys

filterapp f xs = lift2 remove (pure xs) $ seq $ map f xs
```

Comment: That works, though it could be more efficient. But why flat-out solve a problem for someone who's trying to learn? What benefit does that provide?